# SQL sum aggregation not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate

I am trying to do feedback count and feedback responded. My query works fine but as soon as i try to aggregate it then it does not work as i expect it to.

```
SELECT 
feedback.client_id,
feedback.location_id,

@response:=(SELECT 
        event.created_date
    FROM
        event
    WHERE event.feedback_id = feedback.feedback_id) 'response',

CASE
    WHEN @response IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END 'responded'

FROM feedback
```

[image: not aggregated]
This above works all fine.
But now when i try to aggregate this table. Things dont work as i expect it to. I basically copy my sql and group by and add count function.

```
SELECT 
feedback.client_id,
feedback.location_id,

@response:=(SELECT 
        event.created_date
    FROM
        event
    WHERE event.feedback_id = feedback.feedback_id) 'response',

-- count feedback for each client+location
COUNT(*) 'count',

-- not working
SUM(CASE
    WHEN @response IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) 'responded'

FROM
feedback

GROUP BY feedback.client_id , feedback.location_id;
```

[image: aggregated]

I should get 3 responded feedback for the first row and 19 for the second row but it shows 2 and 2.

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: my mysql version is 5.7

Comment: Please never use images for data examples. It is waste of time  creating testing environment from image. -1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a variable here, especially as it complicates the **GROUP BY**.
I suggest that it would be cleaner and more efficient to **LEFT JOIN** the table event. This would let you use the column from event elsewhere as needed.
I give you both options.

```
SELECT 
feedback.client_id,
feedback.location_id,
COUNT(*) 'count',
SUM(CASE
    WHEN (SELECT 
        event.created_date
    FROM
        event
    WHERE event.feedback_id = feedback.feedback_id) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) 'responded'
FROM
feedback
GROUP BY feedback.client_id , feedback.location_id;
```

```
SELECT 
f.client_id,
f.location_id,
COUNT(*) 'count',
SUM(CASE
    WHEN  e.created_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) 'responded'
FROM
feedback f
LEFT JOIN event e
ON f.feedback_id = e.feedback_id
GROUP BY f.client_id , f.location_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=abcf8f84254a880c9fbf665d2d3f328e)*

Comment: but i am using that variable in a column not mentioned here. that is the reason why . i stripped it out to make my question more clear

Comment: i could do it without the variable but then i am repeating my code